# How do I split a sentence into individual words using my custom function split()?

Tags: c, arrays, split, strtok

I am trying to split the user's input into separate words and then print each word on a newline.

I have a function `split()` that tries to take care of split each word using the `strtok()` method. When I try to loop through the words in the `Main()` to print them, it simply doesn't.

After compiling, I get two errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10
#define SIZE 256

char *read_line(char *buf, size_t sz) {
  printf("> ");
  fgets(buf, sz, stdin);
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;
  return buf;
}

void split(char *buf, char *words[], size_t max) {
  char *temp = strtok(buf, " ");

  for (int i = 0; words[0] != '\0'; i++) {
    strcpy(words[i], temp);
    temp = strtok(NULL, buf);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *buf = malloc(SIZE);
  char *words = malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));

  while(1) {
    char *input = read_line(buf, SIZE);
    split(input, words, MAX);

    for (int i = 0; words[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something I am doing or not understanding properly?

Comment: The errors might be ugly but they'd be extremely useful in seeing where this might be failing, so please add them to your question.

Comment: *"which look too ugly to paste into this"* - No, they don't.

Comment: And how can you expect the word to be printed without trying to print them?

Comment: since strtok keeps a static copy of your string and modifies it every time you call with strtok(NULL, buf) it is not so surprising. You need to add storage and not just have an array of pointers `char* split[MAX]` instead of strcpy(split[i],temp)  do `split[i] = strdup(temp);`

Comment: Sorry, I actually pasted the wrong code. It isn't much different, but it is my latest attempt. And for the errors, I was hoping someone would just copy my code and compile it themselves -cheeky, I know.

Comment: The second argument to `split` is a pointer to pointers to char (`char**` or `char *[]`). But when you call it you provide a pointer to char (`char*`)

Comment: The first error is in the title. Please check the wording. And terminology. `a` is a character and is a *word* too... but it certainly cannot be split into **several**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues:

This is what you want. The comments explain what was wrong:

```
void split(char* buf, char* words[], size_t max) {
  char* temp = strtok(buf, " ");

  int i = 0;
  while (temp != NULL)            // wrong usage of strtok
  {
    words[i++] = strdup(temp);    // words[i] points nowhere, you need to allocate memory
    temp = strtok(NULL, " ");     // wrong usage of strtok
  }
  words[i] = NULL;                // you didn't terminate the words array
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char* buf = malloc(SIZE);        // this could be "char buf[SIZE];". It's not wrong
                                   // but there's no need for dynamically allocating memory here

  char** words = malloc(MAX * sizeof(char*));   // you need to allocate pointers to char, not char

  while (1) {
    char* input = read_line(buf, SIZE);
    split(input, words, MAX);

    for (int i = 0; words[i] != NULL; i++) {    // you need to check for the NULL pointer
      printf("%s\n", words[i]);                 // not the NUL char
    }
  }
}
```

There is still room for improvement,

- the `split` function doesn't check for `max`,
- at the end of the program the allocated memory is not properly freed
- there is no error checking whatsoever for brevity

[`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) might not be available on your platform, so you might need to implement it yourself (basically 3 lines of code)

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I have asked so many question about this bit of code and only this one has made sense.